# How to write a Dataset into Cassandra table using spark-cassandra-connector?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to save Structured Steaming Dataset into given Cassandra table.

I am using datastax cassandra connector version spark-cassandra-connector_2-11.jar

While I try to save dataSet like below

```
dataSet
    .writeStream()
    .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
    .option("table",table)
    .option("keyspace", keyspace)
    .outputMode("append")
    .start();
```

Throwing error :

> Data source org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra does not support streamed
>   writing

What should be done and how to handle this?

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50037285/writing-spark-structure-streaming-data-into-cassandra

Comment: @Shaido, thank you but i am using open source Cassandra 3.x version. Not a DSE. any suggestion, how the other people are doing ?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with it myself to be honest. Did you see the second answer in the link above? It looks like it should work for Cassandra (not DSE).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing Spark Structure Streaming data into Cassandra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50037285/writing-spark-structure-streaming-data-into-cassandra)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options regarding it:

1. With Spark Cassandra Connector (SCC) version 2.x, Spark < 2.4, and OSS Cassandra, the only choice is to implement custom `forEach` operation, like it's [done here](https://github.com/alexott/dse-playground/blob/master/spark-oss/src/main/scala/com/datastax/alexott/streaming/StructuredStreamingForEach.scala);
2. With Spark Cassandra Connector version 2.x, Spark >= 2.4, and OSS Cassandra, we can use `forEachBatch` with just normal write operation, like [here](https://github.com/alexott/dse-playground/blob/master/spark-oss/src/main/scala/com/datastax/alexott/streaming/StructuredStreamingForEachBatch.scala);
3. For DSE, we can just use `data.writeStream().format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")`, as DSE Analytics has custom SCC;
4. Starting with SCC 2.5, DSE-specific functionality is open for OSS Cassandra as well, so we can use it same way as for DSE, as [shown in the docs](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/b3.0/doc/14_data_frames.md#using-with-spark-structured-streaming).